# Probability: Associativity of symbols in Conditional Probabiltiy

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

I have been reading various topics on Probability and some conditional probability are denoted like this:

$P(A | B \cap C)$

Now does this represent:

$P(A | (B \cap C))$

or

$P((A|B) \cap C)$

Comment: the 1st representation is right one

Comment: How do you define P((A|B)∩C) and where did you see this notation in use? Let us recall that (A|B) is not an event, in fact (A|B) does not exist.

Comment: @Did, I didn't see P((A|B)∩C) anywhere. All I saw was P(A|B∩C). I'm asking what does P(A|B∩C) interpret out of those two possible choices ?

Comment: And the point is there is no choice... Cool, eh?

Comment: @Did Sorry, couldn't get you.

Comment: ?? There is no choice because P((A|B)∩C) is absurd hence P(A|B∩C) can only mean $____$.

Comment: @Did Thanks, got that now. Can you post that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no choice because P((A|B)∩C) is absurd (recall that (A|B) is not an event, in fact (A|B) does not exist) hence P(A|B∩C) can only mean $____$.